# scrapy able to check if only next sibling has expected tag?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, nextsibling

Let me post part of html I want to scrape first

```
<div id="hello">
  <p>abc</p>
  <center><img src="image_url"></center>
  <p align="center" style="text-align: center;"><b>def</b></p>
  <center><img src="image_url"></center>
  <p align="center" style="text-align: center;"><b>def</b></p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p align="center" style="text-align: center;"><b>def</b></p>
  <center><img src="image_url"></center>
  <p align="center" style="text-align: center;"><b>def</b></p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <center><img src="image_url"></center>
</div>
```

I am trying to scrape the text in p and src of image which is the `image_url` in order.
The thing is, the html I showed above is actually not static, all pages have different structure which means sometimes there'll be more `p` tags before having `center` tag which includes `img src`

Since the `p` and `center` tags are randomly structured in each pages, I was thinking of getting all the `p` tags for example using `response.css('#hello p')` then loop through all the `p` to get text but while getting the text from current `p` tag while looping, also check if next sibling has a `center` tag, if do then get the `src` append it.

I found something like that by doing `p.xpath('following-sibling::center[1]/img/@src').get()` as p is each paragraph duing the iteration.

But I figured, that does not work at all because let's say if I have 4 `p` tags until a `center` I will actually get 4 `img src` because that `p.xpath('following-sibling::center[1]/img/@src').get()` does not just find the next sibling but goes through all the siblings after and see if `center` tag is matched.

I tried googling but I do not see anything mentioning only check if next sibling is some tag.
Anyone has any idea I can get it work so I can save the data in sequence?

Hopefully my explanation makes sense.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions

Comment: So you want to scrape `center` node only if it is an *immediate sibling of `p`*, right? Does `p.xpath('following-sibling::*[1][name()="center"]/img/@src')` solve your problem?

Comment: @JaSON great :D that's truly what I need, can you post it so I can mark it as an answer?  But I have another question I forgot to mention which I solved using a loop but wonder if there's another way?  In my script above after a `p` there MIGHT be one `center` but what if there's multiple? Is there an easy way to do it instead of looping to check if there's a next image?  Right now I am incrementing `center[1]` by one to see if return is None or not

Comment: I can't provide you with generic solution. For 2 possible `center` nodes in a row it will be `following-sibling::*[(position()=1 and name()="center") or (position()=2 and name()="center" and not(preceding-sibling::*[1][name()="p"]))]/img/@src`. The more nodes there might be - the more complicated and messy XPath it would be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required output

```
p.xpath('following-sibling::*[1][name()="center"]/img/@src')
```